# Member with generic type do not accept concrete instances

Tags: typescript, generics, compiler-errors

In the following example TypeScript compiler doesn't accept the statements

```
this.iMember = new Two();
```

and

```
this.apply(this.member as T)
```

with error message **Type 'Two' is not assignable to type 'T'** although in both cases *new Two()* fulfills the contract *extends IOne*. Does anybody have an idea why and how the proper code should look like?

The problem can be reproduced by pasting the example into  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

**Example:**

```
interface IOne{
    getOne(): string;
}
interface ITwo extends IOne
{
    getTwo(): number;
}
class Two implements ITwo{
     getOne(): string{
        return "One";
    }
    getTwo(): number{
        return 2;
    }
}
class Usage<T extends IOne> {
    iMember: T;
    member: Two;
    constructor(){
        this.iMember = new Two();
        this.member = new Two();
    }
    doApply() {
        this.apply(this.iMember);
        this.apply(this.member as T);
    }
    apply(obj: T)
    {
        let test = obj.getOne();     
    }
}
```

I tried the same example as Java code.

```
interface IOne
{
    String getOne();
}

interface ITwo extends IOne
{
    int getTwo();
}

class Two implements ITwo
{
    @Override
    public String getOne()
    {
        return "One";
    }

    @Override
    public int getTwo()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

class Usage<T extends IOne>
{
    T iMember;
    Two member;

    Usage()
    {
        this.member = new Two();
    }

    void doApply()
    {
        this.apply( this.iMember );
        this.apply( (T) this.member );
    }

    void apply( T obj )
    {
        String test = obj.getOne();
    }
}
```

In that case it works with explicit cast to T. 
In Typescript world it still leads to the same error message. 
The actual question is *why it is legal in Java but not in Typescript*?

Comment: `Two` is not necessarily `T`. Imagine if `T` were `Three` where `class Three extends Two { /* more members here * / }`.

Comment: But even in that case Three still implements the interface IOne and fullfills the contact  _T extends IOne_.

Comment: Exactly, though: It implements `IOne`. `Three` may or may not implement `ITwo`--the transpiler doesn't know that, though. It does know that it `Three` implements `IOne`.

Comment: The point I'm trying to say is that `Two` is not assignable to `T` because `T` could be possibly be a type that `Two` is not assignable to (ex. `Three`). That's why you can't assign `Two` to `T`.

Comment: For example, if `Three` had a method `.getThree()` and was set as `T`, then if you assigned `Two` to `iMember` you would get a runtime error when doing `new Usage().iMember.getThree()`. That's why it throws a compile error when assigning `Two` to `T`.

Comment: Could somebody then please explain why the behavior is different between  TS and Java?